# How to exclude all but one specific jar from Gradle distZip task?

Tags: gradle

On line 192 of https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPlugin.java is:

```
libChildSpec.from(project.getConfigurations().getByName(JavaPlugin.RUNTIME_CLASSPATH_CONFIGURATION_NAME));
```

Since my project is using Spring Boot and it generates a standalone jar, how do I exclude all the other jars from the `distZip` task?

Answer (score 1):

```
distributions {
  main {
    contents {
      into('lib') {
        project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.findAll { file ->
          file.getName() != project.tasks.jar.outputs.files.singleFile.name
        }.each { file ->
          exclude file.name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was after